# Do tarantulas and humans have the same mechanism for growing hair?

Tags: human-biology, arachnology, bio-mechanics

There's hair on my arms.

Tarantulas also have hair on their arms.

Is this the same type of hair?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Arthropod hairs are called setae and are not homologous to human hairs. Each setae forms from a single cell called a trichogen. The hair follicles in mammals contain 20 different cell types and produce hairs made of keratin. Arthropod hairs are made of chitin rather than keratin.